# How to calculate projective resolutions of modules

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $R=k[x,y]$, where $k$ is a field. Let $M=R/(x^2,y^2)$ and $N=R/(x,y)$.

Find a free resolution of $P_{\bullet}$ of $M$.

Find a free resolution of $Q_{\bullet}$ of $N$.

I have no idea of how to calculate the above free resolutions.

I know you have following exact maps exist

$\cdots \rightarrow P_2\rightarrow P_1\xrightarrow{d_1^P} P_0\xrightarrow{\pi _1} M=R/(x^2,y^2)\rightarrow 0$ and

$\cdots \rightarrow Q_2\rightarrow Q_1\xrightarrow{d_1^Q} Q_0\xrightarrow{\pi _2} N=R/(x,y)\rightarrow 0$

I know $\text{im(d}_{n+1})=\text{ker(d}_n)$ in each of the maps. The key is to find differentials which are matrices and equate them with exactness property of complex. Since $\pi _1$ and $\pi _2$ are surjective then are $d_1^P=\text{ker(}\pi _1)=(x^2 \text{ }y^2)$ matrix and $d_1^Q=\text{ker(}\pi _2)=(x \text{ }y)$ matrix?

Then I don't know what more to do calculate free resolutions.

Comment: You cannot calculate them, because they are not unique. There are several canonical resolutions, such as the bar resolution, but it is usually useless for computations. Your examples are special cases of [Koszul complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koszul_complex) for regular sequences.

Comment: You need to be able to compute with $R$-modules. I would phrase your last few sentences differently: first, the key is to find free modules and maps between them which satisfy the exactness property. Second, "$d_1^P = \ker (\pi_1)$" doesn't make sense.

Comment: So as I think you've already done: choose $P_0 = R$ and let $\pi_1: R \to M$ be the obvious map. Its kernel is the ideal $J = (x^2, y^2)$. View $J$ as an $R$-module; now you need to find a free $R$-module and a surjection onto $J$, for example the map $R \oplus R \to J$ sending $(1,0)$ to $x^2$ and $(0,1)$ to $y^2$. Find the kernel of this and find a free module which maps onto that kernel, and repeat as necessary.